# How to get data from object which is input from parent component.

Tags: angular, components, interaction

I have parent component which is getting data object from service and stored it in value: item.

Next, by html binding I sending it to child component:

```
<app-employee-form *ngIf="!showLoader" [employee]="item"></app-employee-form>
```

In child component I have input annotation and I got employee value:

```
@Input() employee: Employee;
```

And in this point, my problem start.
When I try to use this data on:

```
ngOnInit() {
console.log('Test ->', this.employee);
console.log('Test for name -> ', this.employee.name);}
```

I have in a console:

```
Test -> {"id":1,"name":"Wanda","surname":"Smith","type":"sdfkmsd","selected":false
Test for name ->  undefined
```

I don't understand why I can't get data from property name (or any other property in this case). Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

For this scope you can use ngOnChange angular hook in your child component to wait the input data to load and after do something with it.

Documentation: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Example:

```
ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges) { 
            for (let propName in changes) {     
                let change = changes[propName];     
                let curVal = JSON.stringify(change.currentValue);           
                let prevVal = JSON.stringify(change.previousValue);
                console.log(curVal);   
                console.log(prevVal); 
            } 
        }
```

Comment: It is not working :( - the same problem. Changes show the change. Console log for currentVersion show full json but when i try console.log name property i have undefined :(

On change:
      undefined =>{"id":2,"name":"David","surname":"Haselhoff","type":"Lifeguard","selected":false}
On change: -> Test -> {"id":2,"name":"David","surname":"Haselhoff","type":"Lifeguard","selected":false}
 On change: -> Test for name ->  undefined

Comment: May be the patent component sending the name field empty.

Comment: In console output name property has value :( like above

Answer (score 0):

Because at the time the data is not available yet. Try

```
if(this.employee) {
console.log(this.employee.name);
}
```

Comment: So why a moment earlier data is available?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you don't have data yet.

What you see in the console is evaluated value which happens later. If you are using the chorm console then you can see one yellow icon which will give more info.

### Fix

Access this value in ngAfterViewInit. If you still not able to access then there could be issue with Angualr Change Detector cycle. You can use `setTimeout` for the same.

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  public _employee;

  get employee(): any {
     return this._employee;
  }

  @Input("employee")
  set employee(employee: any) {
     this._employee= employee;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     console.log('Test ->', this._employee);
     console.log('Test for name -> ', this._employee.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Result :( is not ok
After view Init -> Test ->{"id":2,"name":"David","surname":"Haselhoff","type":"Lifeguard","selected":false}
employee-form.component.ts:47 After view Init -> Test for name ->  undefined

Comment: Updated the answer with `setTimeout`.

Comment: There is delayed in evaluating `employee` so you may need to work. btw did it work ?

Comment: Updated the `@Input`  `Setter`. It should work in your case. Since the functions are the part Change Detection mechanism.

Comment: Setter has the same problem :( I haven't an idea what can be not ok.

Comment: Its clear cut case of Asynchronous execution. Could you check the item before you send to child `<app-employee-form *ngIf="!showLoader && item" [employee]="item"></app-employee-form>`

Comment: Made the correction in the answer check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a possibility that `item` becomes empty after `console.log('Test ->', this.employee);` ? You could try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
console.log('Test ->', this.employee);
console.log('Test for name -> ', this.employee.name);
console.log('Test ->', this.employee);
}
```

If employee is undefined on the third output then it may be cleared in the parent component. If that's the case you could update the `ngIf` on the parent to only show when `item` has a value.

```
<app-employee-form *ngIf="!showLoader && item" [employee]="item"></app-employee-form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone, for help. Your ideas give me one one idea. I check it and object which I have in child component class is a STRING. 
I declared it as Employee but like ts/js everything can be something different in runtime :(.

So a solution is something like this:

```
 (JSON.parse(this._employee.toString()) as Employee).name
```

I think that in input we can send only embed simple classes like string, number etc. (like in all examples :))

I want to add that this solution makes value available in every lifecycle hook which was mentioned here:
onInit, OnCHange, ngAfterViewInit